# When digitizing, objects are not saved well

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing

I've some problems with digitizing.

If I draw a line or a polygon, the line or polygon is saved in the attribute list, but not visible and its location is not saved either (when I zoom to the object it goes to coordinates 0,0).

Both the project CRS and layer CRS are the same.

Sometimes it happens, sometimes not, and I don't have any idea what I might be doing differently.
If it happens, most of the time QGIS crashes when I try to save the changes.

Thanks, 
Silke

I'm using QGIS, Lisboa version

Comment: And also if I ask the area of the polygon, I get NULL.. So it isn't saved, but it does appear in the attribute list.

Comment: What type of file are you saving to: shapefile, spatialite, postgis,...

Comment: Is the style set in such a way that there must be a correct value in the attribute table? This would be case if you set the style for a categorized classification and did not have a null/default style. (Does not explain the 0,0 coords tho)

Comment: @AndreJoost: I'm using a shapefile, I don't have experience with the other ones.

Comment: @Willy: The object should be visible, as colour is also set for null-value. As you say, I would not explain 0,0 coordinates and a null value when calculating the area. 

Thanks to both!

Comment: Maybe load up the tutorial data sets for QGIS and make sure those work for you.

Comment: Is it possible that the polygon border intersects itself? Can you upload the zipped shapefile somewhere? If you are on Windows, you can install another version of QGIS (stable or Master) in parallel with OSGeo4W-setup. There are some bugs in the standalone installer.